# Exercise 2.51 H. Abels. Pseudo differential and singular integral operator an introduction with applications

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Exercise 2.51 Let $\langle \xi\rangle =\sqrt{1+|\xi|^2}$. Prove that for any $s\in\mathbb{R}, \alpha\in\mathbb{N}_{0}^{n}$ there is some $C_{s,\alpha}>0$ such that
$$|\partial_{\xi}^{\alpha} \langle \xi\rangle^s|\leq C_{s,\alpha}(1+|\xi|)^{s-|\alpha|}\quad \text{ for all } \xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$$

Hint. Consider the function $f(a,x):=(a^2+|x|^2)^{m/2}$, where $a\in\mathbb{R}, x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Use that $f$ is homogeneus of degree $m$, i.e., $f(ra,rx)=r^mf(a,x)$ for all $r>0, a\in\mathbb{R}, x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Hello. I am trying to use the hint but I don't know how to use it. I tried not to use it and directly applied induction on the multi index large but the problem gets complicated. How does the homogeneous function f help solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I have solved!
If $f(ra,r\xi)=r^sf(a,\xi)$ then
$r^{|\alpha|}(\partial_{\xi}^{\alpha}f)(ra,r\xi)=r^s\partial_{\xi}^{\alpha}f(a,\xi)$
\begin{eqnarray} 
\partial_{\xi}^{\alpha}f(a,\xi)&\leq& r^{|\alpha|-s} C_{\alpha,s} \\
&=&C_{\alpha,s} (1+|\xi|)^{s-|\alpha|}
\end{eqnarray}
where $r=(1+|\xi|)^{-1}$ and $C_{\alpha,s}=\sup_{(a,\xi)}(\partial_{\xi}^{\alpha}f)(ra,r\xi)$